# Merging data frames based on several conditions

Tags: r, data-wrangling

I have 2 dataframes.

```
df1 <- data.frame(
oID = c(111,112,113,114,115,116,117,118,119,120),
x1 = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
x2 = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
y1 = c(10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1),
y2 = c(10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1)
)

df2 <- data.frame(
oID = (115,116,117,118,119,120,121,122,123),
sID = c(105,106,107,108,109,110,111,112,113),
x1 = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9),
x2 = c(1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2)
)
```

I want to add specific cases from df2 to df1.
I only want to add cases, if the sID of the case matches with any of the oID in df1.

When adding a case from df2 to df1 I want to make some additional operations:

- I want the case to keep some variables (oID, x1,x2,..).
- I want to add some variables to the case (y1,y2,...). The levels of the added variables should be copied from the case with the matching oID in df1.

**Example**: Look at the case **oID 123** from df2. It's **sID is 113** which matches with a case in df1. I want to create a new case in df1 with the following characteristics:
*oID = 123; x1 = 9; x2 = 2; y1 = 8; y2 = 8*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a `tidyverse` approach. First, add rows from `df1` to a `semi_join` of `df1` and `df2`. This will add the x values on matched rows between `sID` and `oID`. Then, all that is missing are the y values. If there's an `sID` value (and not missing or `NA`), then it will `match` the `oID` and use that y value.

```
library(tidyverse)

bind_rows(
  df1,
  semi_join(
    df2,
    df1,
    by = c("sID" = "oID")
  )
) %>%
  mutate(across(y1:y2, ~ifelse(!is.na(sID), .[match(sID, oID)], .))) %>%
  select(-sID)
```

An alternative is to combine rows after doing a series of two consecutive joins:

```
bind_rows(
  df1,
  semi_join(
    df2,
    df1,
    by = c("sID" = "oID")
  ) %>%
    left_join(
      df1[, c("oID", "y1", "y2")],
      by = c("sID" = "oID")
    ) %>%
      select(-sID)
)
```

**Output**

```
   oID x1 x2 y1 y2
1  111  1  1 10 10
2  112  2  2  9  9
3  113  3  3  8  8
4  114  4  4  7  7
5  115  5  5  6  6
6  116  6  6  5  5
7  117  7  7  4  4
8  118  8  8  3  3
9  119  9  9  2  2
10 120 10 10  1  1
11 121  7  2 10 10
12 122  8  2  9  9
13 123  9  2  8  8
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly you can merge the tables and then compare some of the values and replace them. Thereafter you just clean up some columns again.

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df1)
setDT(df2)

merged <- merge(df1, df2, by.x = "oID", by.y = "sID", all.x = T)
merged[!is.na(oID.y), oID := oID.y][!is.na(x1.y), x1.x := x1.y][!is.na(x2.y), x2.x := x2.y]
merged <- merged[, .(oID, x1.x, x2.x, y1, y2)]
setnames(merged, names(df1))

merged

    oID x1 x2 y1 y2
 1: 121  7  2 10 10
 2: 122  8  2  9  9
 3: 123  9  2  8  8
 4: 114  4  4  7  7
 5: 115  5  5  6  6
 6: 116  6  6  5  5
 7: 117  7  7  4  4
 8: 118  8  8  3  3
 9: 119  9  9  2  2
10: 120 10 10  1  1
```

**data**

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  oID = c(111,112,113,114,115,116,117,118,119,120),
  x1 = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
  x2 = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
  y1 = c(10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1),
  y2 = c(10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1)
)

df2 <- data.frame(
  oID = c(115,116,117,118,119,120,121,122,123),
  sID = c(105,106,107,108,109,110,111,112,113),
  x1 = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9),
  x2 = c(1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2)
)
```

Comment: Thank you. Clarification: I want to keep all rows in df1 after merging. 
In the example data provided this should result into a merged df with 13 cases. The 10 cases from df1 and 3 cases from df2 (oID 121,122,123 with sID 111,112,113)